# ffdshow h.264 audio desync

Tags: video, h.264, ffdshow

When I encode video with ffdshow with h.264, the audio is out of sync. At the very beginning of the video, the picture freezes for about 1 second, while the audio plays fine, resulting in the audio being that 1 second ahead of the picture throughout the entire video.

Any ideas on possible causes or, obviously, solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with VirtualDub. Use **x264vfw** which includes a specific fix in its settings labeled "VirtualDub Hack".